# Apply a Coupon automatically for Product Category or Multiple categories - Woocommer 5.9

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, code-snippets

This is regarding Woocommerce (using version 5.9) - to apply coupon code automatically when below condition met.

I am using below code to Automatically apply coupon on products (or multiple products in an array), on the basis of Product ID (here, in our case say, 7974).

This works perfectly fine, when the same product is in Cart (for which the ID is mentioned or multiple IDs in an array, in below code snippet)

However, I want to have the Coupon Applied automatically for ALL products from a particular or specified Product Category (Say Bags, or Kurtis).

1. So, what we need to change or update in the below code, so as to apply the Coupon for the whole product category or multiple categories (with their IDs in array), automatically.

As adding each product ID manually is not possible and very cumbersome. Specially, when one have lots of products in each category.

2. Also, do we need to use the Slug of product category, or ID or some other (on that updated code)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'vas_apply_matched_coupons' );
  
function vas_apply_matched_coupons() {
  
    $coupon_code = 'less120'; 
  
    if ( WC()->cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) ) return;
  
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
  
    // this is your product ID
    $autocoupon = array( 7974 );
  
    if ( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $autocoupon ) ) {   
        WC()->cart->apply_coupon( $coupon_code );
        wc_print_notices();
    }
  
    }
  
}
```

Can you please suggest on this and share the updated code, in order to work with whole product category, rather than adding each product ID manually in this code snippet.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not use the *woocommerce_before_cart* hook: it's a template hook used to render something before the WooCommerce cart. It makes more sense to use the *woocommerce_before_calculate_totals* instead.

If you want to apply a coupon if there's at least one product from the specific category, your code should look like this:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'auto_apply_coupon_for_specific_categories', 10, 1 );
function auto_apply_coupon_for_specific_categories( $cart ) {
  $coupon_code = 'less120'; 

  if ( $cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) ) {
    return;
  }
  
  $discount_categories = array(1,2,3); // an array of terms IDs or slugs
  $coupon_should_be_applied = false;
  
  foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
    $product_belongs_to_discount_category = has_term( $discount_categories, 'product_cat', $product_id );
  
    if ( $product_belongs_to_discount_category ) {
      $coupon_should_be_applied = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  if ( ! $coupon_should_be_applied ) {
    return;
  }

  $cart->apply_coupon( $coupon_code );
}
```

Comment: Hello @Artemy-Kaydash,  Are you sure, that I should use the hook "woocommerce_before_calculate_totals". As I could not find the hook with this name for Cart page. Or do you mean to say, "woocommerce_before_cart_totals". In either case, I tried, but the code seems not working for me. The discount coupon is not getting applied at all. However, when I tried to replicate by manually entering the Coupon, it is working. Can you please check the code again. Have you tested the code Live on site. Should I share my site URL to test with. Please suggest

Comment: Hello @Artemy Kaydash,  I am asking about hook as referred here - https://www.tychesoftwares.com/woocommerce-cart-page-hooks-visual-guide-with-code-examples/ .Can you please check the code again. Have you tested the code Live on site. Please suggest. I used category ID, with minimum amount condition of Rs. 5000/- and tried to Add items of same category in cart and tested when Total is above Rs. 5000/-, but unfortunately, coupon is not getting applied. My code worked with same Coupon and when I used one Product ID in my own code. So Coupon actually is correct. Not sure what is happening.

Comment: @Shweta sorry to hear that. Yes, I tested the code from my answer in my testing environment, and it worked just like expected.

Comment: Does array needs to be like this- array('1','2','3') instead of just array (1,2,3) means to be with inverted comma. Also there is a line after array, that reads - "$coupon_should_be_applied = false;" that is FALSE. Could this be the reason. I tried my code it worked with same coupon code. But then removed mine, and added yours, with same coupon and Category ID in array, but it did not worked. What else might be needed. Also I could not find Hook with this name for Cart page - woocommerce_before_calculate_totals as per above URL. Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: It can be an array of IDs or slugs. $coupon_should_be_applied is set to false because we set it to true only if a product from the discount categories exists in the cart. You don't see the hook I use in the tutorial you've mentioned, because the tutorial shows template hooks, which, as I said, used to show custom data, not to do any calculations or cart modifications.

Comment: After making so many tests, I found that it works only if I remove the Minimum Spend amount from that coupon itself. I need to use and set that Min Amt. Value. Say I entered USD 70 as Min Spend. Then I tried increasing Qty of the item from Same category so that it crosses USD 70, but still it did not applies coupon. So I think code needs to be refined in this case. Although If I remove the Min. Spend condition, then it works.
Also, If I add another product from some other Category for which we did not entered ID in array (means NO discount set), including the Category with coupon..

Comment: ... to be applied, the coupon still applies (we have alredy removed Min. spend conditn,. here). But then, if we remove the Category with Coupon discount set (in array), and keep only the Category with NO discount (not in array), then also, the coupon kept showing and applied. Even after we Hard Refresh the page. the coupone even shows as applied on Checkout page. Please note: Cache is Not enabled on Cart n Checkout pages. What could be the issue in this case. Can you please try to replicate the same in your testing Env., by 1st adding Min. Spend limit, and by adding some other Category product

Comment: Yeah, you need to modify this code to suit all of your needs. You can use it as a reference.

Comment: OH. OK, thank you !!